# Sorting just one column after grouping it

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

How do you use dplyr in order to arrange individual entries together in one column based on a group?
I was hoping I could group_by email, and then sort each individual column A-Z, but I cannot figure out how to do this without sorting the whole dataframe.
Thank you so much in advance!

**Sample Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  cleanname = c("Steven Smith", "Rob Tan", 'Zachary', "Matthew"),
  dirtyname = c('rob Tan', 'stevesmith','zach', "Matthew"),
  email = c('hello@email.com', 'hello@email.com', 'email2@email.com', 'email2@email.com')
)
```

**Desired End Result**

```
desireddf <- data.frame(
  cleanname = c("Rob Tan", "Steven Smith", "Zachary", "Matthew"),
  dirtyname = c('rob Tan', 'stevesmith','zach', 'Matthew'),
  email = c('hello@email.com', 'hello@email.com', 'email2@email.com', 'email2@email.com')
)
```

**Edit**

Thank you to Sotos for pointing out that my problem could be solved through a fuzzy name match.

Comment: Can you explain logic of order? Why `Matthew` is last?

Comment: Are you sure you just want to arrange? It seems that you might need some sort of fuzzy matching there

Comment: Hi @PoGibas, there is no logic to the order. The gist of the situation is that A is in a row with B where B is in a row with A. There are also some situations with 3 different people, so A-B, B-C, C-A matching.

Comment: @Sotos, actually, you're right. A fuzzy matching would serve me well, I overlooked that but makes perfect sense now. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `amatch`-function from the `stringdist`-package:

```
library(stringdist)
df %>% 
  mutate(dirtyname = dirtyname[amatch(tolower(cleanname), tolower(dirtyname), maxDist = 3)],
         email = email[amatch(tolower(cleanname), tolower(dirtyname), maxDist = 3)])
```

which gives:

> ```
>      cleanname  dirtyname            email
> 1 Steven Smith stevesmith  hello@email.com
> 2      Rob Tan    rob Tan  hello@email.com
> 3      Zachary       zach email2@email.com
> 4      Matthew    Matthew email2@email.com
> ```

The same logic applied with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, `:=` (dirtyname = dirtyname[amatch(tolower(cleanname), tolower(dirtyname), maxDist = 3)],
                  email = email[amatch(tolower(cleanname), tolower(dirtyname), maxDist = 3)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the rows in your data frame represent distinct observations, then it is not appropriate to sort each column independently because the independent vector sorts will make the rows no longer represent an individual observation.

A vector can be sorted many ways, such as with the `order()` function.

```
dirtyname <- dirtyname[order(dirtyname)]
```

Comment: How is this an answer? This doesn't solve the problem it's just commenting on it.

Comment: Hi Len, the rows in the desired dataframe are not distinct observations, but in the process of compiling it, the given dirty dataframe has the two names mixed up because they have the same email address.

Comment: @PoGibas -  I hit the `post` button before I was finished.